# Get all previous items in list based on specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this list:

```
<ul id="tabs-list" class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked" href="#registry" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="1"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked active show" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="3"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="2"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I have the third element `tab#2` which has the class `active`. My goal is to take all the `data-question-id` that are located before the `active` item.

The output should be: `["1"]` because before the `tab2` there is just one item with that attribute.

I can easily get the active item using this code:

```
var active_id = Number($(".tab-pane.active").attr('data-question-id'));
```

But how can I get all the previous item of the `active` item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some built in jQuery methods to achieve the output.

[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

> Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[`.prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

> Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

[`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

> Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object

and [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like the following way:

```js
var active_id = $('.active').parent().prevAll().filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('a').attr('data-question-id');
}).get().map(el => $(el).find('a').attr('data-question-id'));

console.log(active_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs-list" class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked" href="#registry" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="1"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked active show" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="3"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="2"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with pure JS in the functional style.

You query all selectors with the attribute `data-question-id`. Then you map this array to an array of objects with the questions ids and a boolean indicating if these elements hold the `active` class.

Then you find the index of the first object with `active = true` and you slice the array to get all the previous questions ids.

```js
const questions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[data-question-id]'))
  .map(elem => ({
      id: elem.getAttribute('data-question-id'),
      active: elem.classList.contains('active')
   }));
  
const result = questions
    .slice(0, questions.findIndex(elem => elem.active))
    .map(elem => elem.id);
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<ul id="tabs-list" class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked" href="#registry" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="1"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link checked active show" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="3"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" style="width: 25%;"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" data-question-id="2"><i class="tim-icons icon-bulb-63"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
var prevs = []
$(".tab-pane.active").each(function()
{
    if ($(this).attr('data-question-id') == active_id)
    {
        // Do something with previous elements

        prevs = null; // empty array
    }
    else if (prevs)
    {
        prevs.push($(this));
    }
})
```